# How to javascript access controls on another aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I access another page in controls ? ( javascript or jquery )

example:

```
Default.aspx

Devexpress Splitter id="mainSplitter"

Detail.aspx
Button_Click(get Default.aspx in slitter id)
```

thank you

Comment: You're trying to execute a button click on another page?

Comment: yes buton_Click open default.aspx

Comment: Create User Control and add both of the pages